# kivy app stopped responding, message pops up either to wait or quiet forcely

Tags: python, kivy, twisted

I was trying to make a chatting app through kivy and using twisted with it, a made a kv button that starts a method which contains reactor.connectTCP("") function. when i tested the app after pressing the button, it gets connected to the server but after that it don't changes the screen and it stops responding.

chat.py:-

```
from twisted.internet import protocol,reactor

class ChatClient(protocol.Protocol):
    def connectionMade(self):
        self.transport.write("hlo")

    def dataReceived(self,data):
        print(data)
        #user2.sendMsg(data)

class EchoFactory(protocol.ClientFactory):
    def buildProtocol(self,addr):
        user1.connectuser1()
        return ChatClient()

    def Conn_network(self):
        reactor.connectTCP("localhost",8000,EchoFactory())
        reactor.run()


from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.relativelayout import RelativeLayout
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen, ObjectProperty

Builder.load_file("chat.kv")
Builder.load_file("chat2.kv")


class User1(Screen):
    def connectuser1(self):
        if self.ids.login_page.text=="akash" and self.ids.Password.text=="hello":
            print ("logged in")
            self.parent.current="chat_screen"
        else:
            print("username or password wrong")


class User2(Screen):
    #def sendMsg(self,data):
     #   self.ids.show_msg.text +=4

    def connectuser2(self):
        self.ids.show_msg.text +=self.ids.txt_msg.text +'\n'
        self.ids.txt_msg.text =''

user1=User1()
sm=ScreenManager()
sm.add_widget(User1(name="login_screen"))
sm.add_widget(User2(name="chat_screen"))
class ChatApp(App,EchoFactory):

    def build(self):
        return sm
if __name__=="__main__":
    ChatApp().run()
```

chat.kv

```
<User1>:
    login:login_page
    RelativeLayout:

        TextInput:
            on_parent:self.focus = True
            id:login_page
            pos_hint:{"center_x": .5, "center_y": .7}
            size_hint: .3, .2
        TextInput:
            on_parent:self.focus = True
            id:Password
            pos_hint:{"center_x": .5, "center_y": .5}
            size_hint: .3, .2
        Button:
            text:"send"
            pos_hint:{"center_x": .5, "center_y": .3}
            size_hint: .3, .2
            on_press:
                app.Conn_network()
```

server.py:-

```
from twisted.internet import reactor,protocol

class Echo(protocol.Protocol):
    def dataReceived(self,data):
        print("connected")
        self.transport.write(data)

class EchoFactory(protocol.Factory):
    def buildProtocol(self,addr):
        return Echo()

reactor.listenTCP(8000, EchoFactory())
reactor.run()
```

Comment: I guess the twister thingy is running after you call it and does not stop. kivy waits until the function is finished to update the gui. To avoid that you should look into threading. Here is a sample app which uses threading https://gist.github.com/PalimPalimPalim/f770f114d5a661ae093f67673776c9ed hope it helps :)

Comment: @PalimPalim thankyou for your help, i found my mistake that i am calling reactor.run() which runs continousely and dont stop(as u said), i removed it and it worked. But the problem comming is that i am unable to call buildprotocoal function because i dont know what the addr is in buildprotocoal.

Comment: sorry. I don't have a clue about protocols and stuff...